# What is the proper way to get an element from an array with array destructuring?

Tags: javascript, arrays, destructuring

Pretty much everything is in the title but i'll give you an example :

```
// i can't know the content of this string but for the exemple she's here
let str = 'elem-0, elem-1, elem-2, elem-3';

// how to properly write this line because this line is not write in an array 'destructuring way'
let array = str.split(',')[0];

// return me : "elem-0" (and he has to)
console.log(array);
```

Comment: `let [array] = str.split(',');`

Comment: Depends on what you want to achieve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can destructure array elements like

```
let [first, second, ...rest] = str.split(',');
```

Basically it works by index, the first variable being arr[0], second being arr[1](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Array_destructuring) and so on. `...rest` will hold the remaining items in the array which aren't destrucutred

Check the [MDN documentation for Array Destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Array_destructuring)

Comment: You should avoid answering questions that have duplicates that answer the questions in detail (Based on your profile, I see you're doing this frequently). You should at least take the time to select and link the duplicates. If the questions are answered again and again, there will be thousands of short and badly answered questions and the well answered questions will be lost.